# d3 make g continue on the same line

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to create a [dot matrix graph](https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/images/anatomy/dotmatrix.png) from scratch.
My approach is to add a group for each category type and then create an equivalent number of divs.

However, g, being block element, starts as a new vertical layer.

[Current Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyfGm.png)

Is there any other way I can group/loop through inner elements other than "g"? (Something like"span")

My current code:

```
<body>
    <div id="container" class="svg_container">
        <div class="all">
        </div>
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<style>
    #container{
    width: 90%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    //border: 1px solid red;
    padding:0;
    }
    .all{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 250px;
        justify-content: space-between;


    }

    .g{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

    }
    .cell{
        width:20px;
        height: 20px;
        //margin-top: 2px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        margin: 0.5%;
        border: 1px solid blue;

    }
</style>
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>
<script>
 <body>
    <div id="container" class="svg_container">
        <div class="all">
        </div>
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<style>
    #container{
    width: 90%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    //border: 1px solid red;
    padding:0;
    }
    .all{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 250px;
        justify-content: space-between;


    }

    .g{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

    }
    .cell{
        width:20px;
        height: 20px;
        //margin-top: 2px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        margin: 0.5%;
        border: 1px solid blue;

    }
</style>
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>
<script>
 var colors= ["#4194CA","#31ADB9","#77D8B5","#BAE3C3","#EFFFD0"];
 d3.csv("data.csv", data =>{
        console.log(data);

    d3.select(".graph").selectAll("g")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .classed("g", "true")
          .style("background-color", (d,i) => colors[i])
          .selectAll("div")
          .data(d =>[...Array(parseInt(d.All)).keys()])
          .enter()
          .append("div")
          .classed("cell", "true")
          .style("background-color", "inherit");

         })

</script>
```

Adding a sample of data format (one row):

```
18 - 34:"29%"
35 - 64:"42%"
65 and up:"37%"
All:"37%"
```

I am trying to map [All] to number of divs in a color.

Comment: edit your code and remove duplicate stuff. Since when is `g` allowed to be a child of `div` and `div` a child of `g`?

Comment: dump all markers in one group and color the background of an individual marker with the correct color. maybe `d3.range` is a lot easier than that `Array` stuff

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Even if I add d3.range, how do I create a particular number of divs for each? Edited question to add the data format and what I  am trying to do.

Comment: Just to check, have you come across the `d3-scalePoint`? Not quite sure how much of "from scratch" you want to do.

Comment: I don't see much CSV in your data sample. will `paseInt` handle the `%` correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are creating a parent g element for each row of data:
You want to have all the divs in the same parent.
You have several options at your disposal. One could be to flatten your array, eg,
from [[1,2,...,37], [1,2,...,24], ...] to something like [0,0,...,0,1,..1,2,...]

Your code can be

```
var colors= ["#4194CA","#31ADB9","#77D8B5","#BAE3C3","#EFFFD0"];
 d3.csv("data.csv", data =>{
        console.log(data);
        var newdata = d3.merge(data.map((d, i)=>d3.range(parseInt(d.All)).map(v=>i)));
        console.log(newdata);

d3.select(".graph").append("g").attr('class','g')
      .selectAll("div")
      .data(newdata)
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .classed("cell", "true")
      .style("background-color", d=>colors[d]);

     })
```

`